# Proxy requires password and user name

Tags: high-sierra, proxy, web-browser

Running High Sierra.

I started getting this message when I first open chrome:

`the proxy http://11.adams-aqua.ga/ requires user name and password`

A couple of weeks ago I stopped being able to browse with any browser because some problem with the proxies. Searching the internet I found as a solution to just disable all proxy settings.

I found this solution rather lame, but it worked. Also I read that it was better to have use some proxy as it would take less time to request pages from servers.

I would like to just have whatever is normal as proxy settings but failed to find a tutorial explaining this.

Thanks!

Comment: This on a computer at home, school, or at work? How is the computer connected to the Internet?

Comment: @GrahamMiln It is at home. Just over wi-fi. The message appears only once, then I can surf the web normally.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1350239/normal-proxy-settings-in-osx-high-sierra

Answer (score 1):

Most users do not use a proxy server when browsing the web from home.

On macOS the computer wide proxy settings are found in **Network** settings of **System Preferences.app**. See [Remove Proxy Settings](https://ucsd.libguides.com/c.php?g=669443&p=4732317):

1. Select **Apple** (menu) > **System Preferences…**
2. Select **Network**
3. Select **Advanced…** for the active Wi-Fi network
4. Select the **Proxies** tab
5. Disable all protocols checkboxes, before selecting **OK**, then **Apply**

Comment: Thanks, I removed the proxy settings, but I figured that it was actually an extension that was messing with chrome. Disabled it, now the prompt is gone.

Comment: Which extension did you remove? Knowing the name might help others who find the question in the future.

Comment: True! It as extension called "ZenMate VPN"

Comment: Should I answer my own question?

Comment: You can, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer